# How to bind MutableLiveData<Boolean> to checkBox

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

The problem is that when I click the button the Toast message always says `checked` is true, even if I uncheck the checkbox

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: MainActivityLayoutBinding

    var checked = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        checked.value = true

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity_layout)
        binding.checked = checked.value

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.showValue.setOnClickListener{

            Toast.makeText(this, checked.value.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }
}
```

Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="checked"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:checked="@={checked}"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Salva"
            android:id="@+id/showValue"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: I think it is not possible like that. You have to use a view model for that. And one thing more, binding.checked = checked.value, here we are just getting the live data value, not doing anything related to observer. And if you are not using view models, then simply add checkchange listener.

Comment: Ok I will try. So you are saying that binding.checked = checked.value assigns the value to the checkbox only once and than doesn't care about it anymore, right?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set checked.value = true
Try to remove this line

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
binding.checked = checked.value
```

and observe to `live-data` change , then update binding view

```
checked .observe(this , Observer { 
             binding.checked = it
        })
```

Comment: It does not work. I don't think I can remove that line since I need to assign a variable to the xml layout <variable>

Comment: You are right. I tried modifying the boolean value when the button is clicked and it changes the value even without that line, but I can't make it work when I check/uncheck the checkbox